# animated scroll is very buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I've been trying to figure this out for awhile and can't seem to get it.

I use a navigation consisting of circles (see website below) and when the user clicks on one, it forwards him/her to the corresponding slide.

When you click around, it will sometimes slide all the way back to the beginning of the window (margin-left = 0).  If it doesn't do it at first,  just click around for a second or two and you'll eventually see it.

http://dan.stargroupdev.com/

Here's the code that's buggy:

```
$("#footer-slidenav .links a").click(function () {
  // Get nav index
  var slidenum = $(this).attr("id").slice(3);
  // Setup slide selector with string to avoid issues
  var slidetext = ".slide:eq(" + slidenum + ")";
  slidenum = $(slidetext).offset().left;
  console.log("Top: " + slidenum);
  var offset2 = 0;
  // Find window offset to center slide if screen is bigger than 1000px (size of one slide)
  if (($(window).width() - 1000) / 2 > 0) {
    offset2 = ($(window).width() - 1000) / 2;
  }
  // Slide window to slide # that was clicked
  $("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)").animate({
    scrollLeft: slidenum
  }, 1000, function () {
    console.log("Middle: " + slidenum);
    // Callback to center slide and give a nice little animated touch
    slidenum = $(slidetext).offset().left;
    console.log("Bottom: " + slidenum);
    $("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)").animate({
      scrollLeft: (slidenum - offset2)
    }, "fast");
  });
  return false;
});
```

I tried things like `$("html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)")` along with a few other similar possible solutions, but the bug is still there.

Any advice would be great and I'm more than happy to entertain any ideas you guys might have.

Thanks.

Comment: check that your variable slidenum is not changing when it isn't supposed to be changing (scope)... do something like console.log("A--"+slidenum); console.log("B--"+slidenum); after each time you set a value to the slidenum variable.

Comment: I added the code as seen above so you can look at the console.  It seems to be calling the callback twice for some reason.

Comment: the double callback is called because you animate both the body and the html (when you select **html, body**, it selects two elements instead of one). Two animations at once are evil.

Comment: If I only select one, it doesn't work on all browsers properly.  I've done `html,body` a thousand times over on different websites and it's worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had a leftover piece of code in another JS file.  Sorry for wasting your time guys, that's why it was getting messed up.

I appreciate your answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Ill propose an entirely new solution(mostly new)

```
$("#footer-slidenav .links a").click(function () {
    var slidenum = $(this).attr("id").slice(3);
    var slidetext = ".slide:eq(" + slidenum + ")";

    offset = $(slidetext).position().left;
    console.log(offset );

    $("body").animate({
        scrollLeft: offset
    });
});
```

Could you give it a try?

Comment: I'll try it on Monday, but I don't really see how this is much different other than the fact that it's `body` instead of `body, html` which I've tried a thousand times over.

Comment: The other thing is I removed the callback animation

Comment: I tried that.  Now it just shoots it back to the beginning (the callback would make it work at least after it went to the beginning).  In the console, the numbers are still correct though.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to test the site without the class `front` on `body`. The script http://dan.stargroupdev.com/sites/all/themes/starsite/js/starsite.js use this class with result to create the unwanted behavior I think. If I remove it with firebug it works ok for me. Check it and give feedback to see if this is true.

Answer (score 0):

First of all can I suggest [Arial Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/)'s [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin? It's awesome and works like a charm.

You can use offsets to center the final position.

If you want some kind of easing then you can use them to make the animation look more *natural*. What about an elastic animation?

I've been using this plugin for over one year, without finding any problem.

Also, remember to `.stop()` the scrolled/animated element.